# Recursion in Mybatis SQL causing stack overflow while compile

Tags: java, sql, xml, recursion, mybatis

I have a class with recursive relation like below.

```
   Class A{
      String id;
      String op;
      String val;
      List<A> aList;
   }
```

I am using MySQL MyBatis to generate a query like below.

```
 <sql id="testRecursion">
        <foreach collection="A.aList" item="aList" open="(" separator=" UNION " close=")">
            <if test="aList.op == null">
                (
                SELECT sum(val) as val FROM
                FROM test_data
                WHERE id = #{aList.id} 
                )
            </if>

            <if test="aList.op== 'AND'">
                SELECT max(val) as val FROM
                <include refid="testRecursion"/>
            </if>

            <if test="aList.op== 'OR'">
                SELECT min(val) as val FROM
                <include refid="testRecursion"/>
            </if>
       </foreach>
  </sql>
```

It is giving below error with stack overflow exception like this while on the compilation.

```
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLIncludeTransformer.applyIncludes(XMLIncludeTransformer.java:74) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLIncludeTransformer.applyIncludes(XMLIncludeTransformer.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
```

Can someone please help me out here, how to implement recursion in mybatis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because `include` element does not support recursion, that is you can't include the sql snippet from itself.

If you switch to velocity scripting engine you can implement what you need with a macro that is allowed to reference itself.

Unfortunately, you haven't provided the invoking code for your snippet so my example may differ a bit and you need to adjust it but it should give you the idea.

Given this definition of A:

```
public class A {
  Integer id;
  String op;
  Integer val;
  List<A> nodes;
  // setters/getters omitted for brevity
```

You can define the mapper like this:

```
class MyMapper {
   Integer getRecursive(@Param("A") A a);
}
```

And query in xml:

```
<select id="getRecursive" lang="velocity" resultType="int">
    #macro(node $a)
        #if( ! $a.op )
            SELECT sum(val) as val FROM A
            WHERE id = ${a.id} 
        #else
            SELECT
            #if( $a.op == "AND" )
                max(val) as val
            #else
                min(val) as val
            #end
            FROM (
                #repeat( $a.nodes $aNode "UNION ALL" )
                   #node($aNode)
                #end
            )
        #end
    #end

    select val FROM (
        #node($_parameter.A)
    )
</select>
```

You need to [configure](http://www.mybatis.org/velocity-scripting/) the project to make velocity available.

The downside is that you can't bind parameters via prepared statement (note `id = ${a.id}` and not `id = @{a.id}`).

Here's how I invoked the mapper method:

```
@Test
public void testRecursive() {
    A a = or(leaf(1), and(leaf(2), leaf(3)));
    assertThat(sut.getRecursive(a), equalTo(1));
}

private A leaf(int id) {
    A a = new A();
    a.setId(id);
    return a;
}

private A or(A ... ops) {
    return operation("OR", ops);
}

private A and(A ... ops) {
    return operation("AND", ops);
}

private A operation(String operation, A ... ops) {
    A a = new A();
    a.setOp(operation);
    a.setNodes(Arrays.asList(ops));
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With that little info I assume it is problem with looping references. If I have obj1 and in his list reference to obj2 and vice versa then foreaching bounce between.
If it is not that problem, please elaborate what are you doing with your data

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, you are right this is exactly the problem is, sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with cycles in data. The problem is with recursive include of sql snippets.